# Wake on LAN not shown as supported, despite works on windows

Tags: networking, home-networking, opensuse, wake-on-lan, home-server

I have installed openSUSE Leap as dual boot. I want to have feature Wake on LAN. When I check in windows "Enable wake on magic packet only" and turn off, it works. When I boot to opensuse and turn the computer off, it does not work.

So I think the problem is not in delivery of this packet but in target network card settings.

I tried:

```
# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Current message level: 0x000060e4 (24804)
                   link ifup rx_err tx_err hw wol
    Link detected: yes
```

Is it the problem of driver? Is it overridable somehow?

Comment: *When I boot to opensuse and turn it off, it does not work.* Are you expecting wake-on-LAN to work after you've turned it off?  Have you tried turning wake-on-LAN on using `ethtool`?

Comment: I mean "when I turn off the computer and nothing manually changing". yes, I tried but: ```# ethtool -s eth0 wol g
Cannot get current wake-on-lan settings: Operation not supported
  not setting wol```

Comment: This is a function of the hardware and BIOS, not the OS. Have you checked in the BIOS for wake on lan settings? “Turning off” and putting it in to “standby” are two different things.